# Search for partial match in numpy structured array python

Tags: python, search, numpy

I have a numpy structured array e.g. B which has the following form

```
array([('J0006+1834', '-99', 0.693748, 2.1e-15),
   ('J0007+7303', 'NRAD', 0.315873, 3.6e-13),
   ('B0011+47', '-99', 1.240699, 5.64e-16), ...,
   ('B2334+61', '-99', 0.49537, 1.93e-13),
   ('J2346-0609', '-99', 1.181463, 1.36e-15),
   ('B2351+61', '-99', 0.944784, 1.63e-14)], 
  dtype=[('Name', 'S10'), ('Type', 'S10'), ('P0', '<f8'), ('P1', '<f8')])
```

I need to be able to search for partial matches of the second column named Type. My array contains values in the secong columns that start with NR and I would like to be able to search for them as a group. I tried np.where and startwidth but I was not successfull. I also tried with wildcards but nothing worked.

Ideally I would like a command like this

```
B[B['Type']=='NR*']
```

which would return alla the elements of the array which in th column Type start with NR.

Thank you for your time and I am looking forward for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `numpy`, you could use [`np.char.startswith`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html):

```
>>> np.char.startswith(d["Type"], "NR")
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> d[np.char.startswith(d["Type"], "NR")]
array([('J0007+7303', 'NRAD', 0.315873, 3.6e-13)], 
      dtype=[('Name', 'S10'), ('Type', 'S10'), ('P0', '<f8'), ('P1', '<f8')])
```

But IMHO this is really more of a [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) problem:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
         Name  Type        P0            P1
0  J0006+1834   -99  0.693748  2.100000e-15
1  J0007+7303  NRAD  0.315873  3.600000e-13
2    B0011+47   -99  1.240699  5.640000e-16
3    B2334+61   -99  0.495370  1.930000e-13
4  J2346-0609   -99  1.181463  1.360000e-15
5    B2351+61   -99  0.944784  1.630000e-14
>>> df[df.Type.str.startswith("NR")]
         Name  Type        P0            P1
1  J0007+7303  NRAD  0.315873  3.600000e-13
```

Admittedly here the syntax is similar enough that there's not much of an advantage either way, but once you want to start performing other operations like grouping, `pandas` starts to shine and using bare `numpy` becomes increasingly inconvenient.